# How do i add my email ID next to the Name in Deedy resume

Tags: deedy-resume

Im able to get the name to the left of the heading but now i need to add my email in small text next to my name. Refer image to see the yellow markings. That is where i expect to put my email in small fonts. How do i do that?

Also i can see a black line to the right of the document. How do i remove it? [image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Can you please show us a compilable example document that reproduces what you see. I got the Deedy resume from https://github.com/deedy/Deedy-Resume, ran the example document and could *not* see such a line. So there must be something special going on in your document.